# Show specific columns

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select specific columns inside a table.

```php
$QColumnsTable = $this->db->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM :table_orders');
```

Display all columns inside a table.

How to display just `orders_id`, `date_purchased` for example ?

Comment: Is this SQL ? If it is, you can do `SELECT orders_id, data_purchased FROM table_orders`.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`; information_schema presents data about your database (structure and routines) in a familiar table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a Where Clause for the column field

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_orders
WHERE field = 'orders_id' OR field = 'date_purchased ';
```

But **parametrization** with **tablenames won't work**.

You have to canocat9nate it like a string